# Make query to Cosmos from azure webapp

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-web-app-service

I have a Cosmos DB running in azure, and I also have the web API in nodejs running in Azure, making a query in local works fine, but when I zip deploy to azure this part of my coding gives me error.

`const CosmosClient = require('@azure/cosmos').CosmosClient;
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

Anybody knows why I am getting this error when trying to require `CosmosClient`?

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was to create a new file in the root folder called `iisnode.yml` and add `nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\{version-here}\node.exe"`
And that dit it.